# Change a CSS display style in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a bit of my javascript code.
I am trying to get my `#showAddress` to `display: block` when the `deliverservice` radio button is clicked/checked.
I've tried looking at some Stack Overflow posts but a lot of them are too advanced for my current level (I just started JavaScript).

```html
<label>Delivery Type</label>
    <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="Pickup" id="pickupService">Pickup
    <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="Deliver" id="deliverService">Deliver
</p>

<div id="showAddress">
<p>
<label for="deliveryAddress">Delivery Address</label><br>
<input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="deliveryAddress" placeholder="Enter street number + name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="deliverySuburb" id="deliverySuburb" placeholder="Enter your [suburb], [state]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="deliveryPostcode" placeholder="Enter your postcode"><br>
    <a href="#" id="sameAddress">Billing address same as Above</a>
</div>
<p>
    <label for="billingAddress">Billing Address</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="billingAddress" placeholder="Enter street number + name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="deliverySuburb" id="billingSuburb" placeholder="Enter your [suburb], [state]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="billingPostcode" placeholder="Enter your postcode"><br>
</p>
<p>
```

I believe the error is happening in my JavaScript, however it's only two functions. The first two lines are my initialise function, which is calling my second function down below.

```js
var showDelivery = document.getElementById("deliverService");
showDelivery.onclick =  showAddress;

function showAddress() {
    document.getElementById("showAddress").style.display= 'block';
}
```

```css
#additionalInformation, #showAddress {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line

```
showDelivery.onclick =  showAddress;
```

to something like this:

```
showDelivery.onclick = function(){showAddress();};
```

Comment: Isnt this putting a function within a function? im just trying to reduce clutter on the page

Comment: You are just telling the function that should be executed onclick. There are other ways to do this that you can check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Comment: And you can check for eventlisteners too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: I am using Chrome and it didnt seem to solve the problem.

Comment: You can try put your script before </body>. You can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/9bmnrcft/

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can set the `onclick` listener on the input element itself (in the html), to directly call the javascript function from the HTML element, rather than cluttering your JavaScript

```
 <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="Deliver" id="deliverService" onclick="showAddress()">Deliver
```

```js
function showAddress() {
    document.getElementById("showAddress").style.display= 'block';
}
```

```css
#additionalInformation, #showAddress {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>Delivery Type</label>
        <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="Pickup" id="pickupService">Pickup
        <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="Deliver" id="deliverService" onclick="showAddress()">Deliver

    <div id="showAddress">
    <p>
    <label for="deliveryAddress">Delivery Address</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="deliveryAddress" placeholder="Enter street number + name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliverySuburb" id="deliverySuburb" placeholder="Enter your [suburb], [state]"><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="deliveryPostcode" placeholder="Enter your postcode"><br>
        <a href="#" id="sameAddress">Billing address same as Above</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <label for="billingAddress">Billing Address</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="billingAddress" placeholder="Enter street number + name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliverySuburb" id="billingSuburb" placeholder="Enter your [suburb], [state]"><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="billingPostcode" placeholder="Enter your postcode"><br>
    </p>
```

**EDIT:** An example of using `addEventListener`

```
document.getElementById("deliverService").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("showAddress").style.display= 'block';
});
```

```js
document.getElementById("deliverService").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("showAddress").style.display= 'block';
});
```

```css
#additionalInformation, #showAddress {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>Delivery Type</label>
        <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="Pickup" id="pickupService">Pickup
        <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="Deliver" id="deliverService">Deliver

    <div id="showAddress">
    <p>
    <label for="deliveryAddress">Delivery Address</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="deliveryAddress" placeholder="Enter street number + name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliverySuburb" id="deliverySuburb" placeholder="Enter your [suburb], [state]"><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="deliveryPostcode" placeholder="Enter your postcode"><br>
        <a href="#" id="sameAddress">Billing address same as Above</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <label for="billingAddress">Billing Address</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="billingAddress" placeholder="Enter street number + name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliverySuburb" id="billingSuburb" placeholder="Enter your [suburb], [state]"><br>
        <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" id="billingPostcode" placeholder="Enter your postcode"><br>
    </p>
```

Comment: I found this method works... however, isnt there a way to do it like i was trying. To call it when it is initialised in javascript. Otherwise i have to weed through my html

Comment: Sure is, i have added another example for using `addEventListener` to listen for a click, and execute some arbitrary function